# Can I have multiple try statements connecting to one except statement?

Tags: python, performance

So I want to be efficient in making code in python, and I am doing something like this:

```py
try:
    #Code A
except:
    #Code A
try:
    #Code B
except:
    #Code B
try:
    #Code B
except:
    #Code B
```

But I want to link all of them to one `except` block so I can use an `else` statement to catch em' all! (Reference intended).
So could I do something like the following?

```
try:
    #Code A
try:
    #Code B
except:
    #Code C
else:
    #Code D
```

I have tried the code, but to my self findings and limited questions that are 'similar' all I get is: `Error: invalid syntax "try:"`. Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: I dunno about *performance*... there should be only one reasonable way to handle your exceptions. I think you should be more concerned about *correctness*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't have multiple try block associated with only one except block. but you can have muliple except block releated to only one try block.

every try block need except block if you didn't provide one you will have an exception.

example of mulitple except block releated to one try block :-

```
try:
    # do something
    pass
except ValueError:
    # handle ValueError exception
    pass
except (TypeError, ZeroDivisionError):
    # handle multiple exceptions
    # TypeError and ZeroDivisionError
    pass
except:
    # handle all other exceptions
    pass
```

suppose you perform some operation in try block and you encountered a problem then first except block will take the control if it can't handle the exception then the below except block will handle it and so on......

Note: if the first except block can handle the exception the next except block does not execute or will not come in action.

Answer (score 4):

You actually don't need those extra `try`s at all. Whenever there's an exception raised inside the `try` block, all code starting there until the end of the block is skipped and the control jumps immediately to the matching `except` block. And as well, the `else` block is executed when the `try` block reachs its end normally. This way you don't need multiple `try` blocks - just concatenate them into one and you'll achieve your aim.

Answer (score 1):

It is always good practice to have more generic except block for a specific exception type.
a single try statement with multiple except block

```
try:
    #put your risky code
    # put another risky code
    pass
# multiple exception block will help to catch exact exception and can perform
# operation
except KeyError:
    pass
except IOError:
    pass
except ValueError:
    pass
except Exception:
    pass
else:
    pass
```